# Value of an integral in the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

I need to verify  the value of the following integral
$$ 4n(n-1)\int_0^1 \frac{1}{8t^3}\left[\frac{(2t-t^2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-\frac{t^{2n+2}}{n+1}-t^4\{\frac{(2t-t^2)^{n-1}}{n-1})-\frac{t^{2n-2}}{n-1} \} \right] dt.$$
The integrand (factor of $4n(n-1)$) included) is the pdf of certain random variable for $n\geq 3$ and hence I expect it be 1.If somebody can kindly put it into some computer algebra system like MATHEMATICA ,I would be most obliged .I do not have access to any CAS software.

PS:-I do not know of any free CAS  software.If there is any somebody may please share

Comment: Also posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Value of an integral](https://mathoverflow.net/q/371159). I will add a pointer to Willie Wong's post on meta: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088) (IMO that answer contains very reasonable advice.)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your integral
$$I_n=\frac{n(n-1)}2 J_n$$ with
$$J_n=\int \frac{\frac{\left(2 t-t^2\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{t^{2 n+2}}{n+1}-t^4
   \left(\frac{\left(2 t-t^2\right)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{t^{2
   n-2}}{n-1}\right)}{t^3}\,dt$$ Now, rewrite $(2t-t^2)=t(2-t)$  to make the integrand
$$\frac{2 t^{2 n-1}}{n^2-1}+\frac{(2-t)^{n+1} t^{n-2}}{n+1}-\frac{(2-t)^{n-1} t^n}{n-1}$$ The first term does make any problem.

Now, remember that
$$\int_0^1 (2-t)^a t^b\,dt=2^{a+b+1} B_{\frac{1}{2}}(b+1,a+1)$$ where appears the incomplete beta function. So, for your definite integral, we have at the end
$$\frac1 {2(n+1)}+2^{2n-1} n \left(\frac{n-1 }{ n+1}B_{\frac{1}{2}}(n-1,n+2)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}(n+1,n)\right)$$ and all of that is $\color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SageMath https://www.sagemath.org/
It has a built-in function to integrate symbolically